# How to detect the location of a single-colour text/logo pattern?

Tags: opencv

I'd like to use opencv to detect a logo/text pattern in an image. I'm interested in the centre-point of the pattern location. Detection needs to be scale (0.5x - 2.0x) and rotation invariant (-/+ 20 degrees).

I have tried SIFT, SURF and FAST. Although the first two often guest the right location, I found them very slow (and I had to resize the image to at least 1200x1600, but that's probably a separate question).

I was hoping there was an algorithm that would only match lines, rather than patterns. For example, I've experimented with `matchShapes()`, but it seems like that method is not rotation & scale invariant.

Pattern:

[image: Pattern]

Image:

[image]

After canny:

[image: Canny]

Comment: I'd say it mainly depends on the environment of the logo. Is your image realisitic on what you finally want to achieve, or do you want to find logos in any context? Answer to the first may be simple, but people work on the latter for years :).

Comment: @jlengrand yes, this image is realistic. In all tests I've done so far, I was able to extract the contours (with a degree of error) of the logo in my target image. My canny/binarize parameters are optimised for my camera & flash light.

Comment: Next question is, are you searching for any logo, or only some you know? Depdning on this, you may simply want a pattern recognition algorithm. In the other case, you need to draw a list of common criteria for your logos and work on those

Comment: hmm... i'm only interested in this typographical logo (the real one has other text/font of course). When you speak of common criteria... what do you mean exactly?

Comment: have you looked at these questions? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=logo+detection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logo recognition - how to improve performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735715/logo-recognition-how-to-improve-performance)

Comment: @vasile I don't think this question is a duplicate. All the other questions regard matching a far more complex pattern (SURF/SIFT/FAST). What I'm asking here is matching of a single-colour typography (or may be even just 'edge matching'). And I'm wondering whether it can be matched easier and faster than the use of SURF/SIFT.

Comment: This seems to be the most common homework for computer vision classes. A bit of personal study will help you. Google it, read and implement yourself what others have done, and you will have a much better understanding on the problem.

Comment: @vasile believe me that I've been trying to get this done for more than a month, and I've tried SURF, SIFT, FAST, ORB and many other techniques and code samples.... Yes - I can Google. I guess all questions on SO can be found on google. However, google does not give any direction. I was hoping for some advice/direction.

Comment: You mentioned earlier that you tried FAST.  Did it not work for you?  It is much much faster than SIFT and SURF...