# How to get croped image captured from CAMERA

Tags: android, image-processing, pattern-matching, android-camera, android-capture

How to get the crop image which are bounded within a section which are shown in Image.

I want my app to capture an image of a book page, which contain 4 image patterns at the corners. I want it to first match those pattern and then to remove all the part which is not available inside the boundary of those 4 images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [OpenCV for Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android) library.

Take a look at these SO discussions:

- Detecting paper on image:
  [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection)
- Detecting logo:
  [Logo recognition - how to improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735715/logo-recognition-how-to-improve-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but This is not an answer for my question, I want to crop automatically according to patterns, In my case, there are four image pattern in my case present at the corners...I want them to recognize and then to crop from there.

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial does it all, toy can download the sources as well:http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

Comment: As mention in question description. Need to auto corp from corner black sections.